# Computing anova table in r

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I know that you can get an anova table by using anova(). However, that's if you have the data already in r (ie you have a file and you read it into r). But I have a printed table as shown below:[image]

How do I compute an anova table from this using r?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use some .png reader or type in the data by hand.

Comment: how would I type in the data by hand?

Comment: Your data set is balanced and small.  It's a matter of simple arithmetic to calculate an ANOVA by hand in these circumstances.

Comment: sorry I'm still very new to anova and I am suppose to compute it.

Comment: "How would I type the data by hand?".  Seriously? Open a text editor.  Start typing.  Separate data values within a row by a space.  Separate rows by new lines.  Save the file.  Read the file into R.  There are variations on the theme.  `tribble` and `textConnection`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as your template for creating the df by hand

```
df <- data.frame(
Gender = c('Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Sub Mean', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Sub Mean', 'Age Mean'),
    Young=c(21,23,19,22,22,23,21.67,21,22,20,21,19,25,21.33,21.5),
    Middle=c(30,29,26,28,27,27,27.83,26,29,27,28,27,29,27.67,27.75),
    Elderly = c(25,22,23,21,22,21,22.33,23,19,20,21,20,20,20.50,21.42)
)

df
```